# DB/2 multiplication in select

Tags: sql, db2

I am writing a query on DB/2 on as/400 to select total weight of goods in warehouse. I have columns weight and count - now what I need is something like:

```
select weight, count, (weight * count) as total from warehouse
```

But this query is not working, i get error message:

```
* use not valid.
```

Could anyone give me an idea what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: be sure that `weight` and `count` have numerical type.

Comment: You are right, it was a wrong type. My bad, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that weight and count have numerical type. If not, change your table design or cast data to numeric type.